# Posso criar uma Foreign Key entre 3 tabelas?

Tags: sql

Eu tenho 3 tabelas principais na minha base de dados:

Actors, MoviesData e SeriesData.

Cada filme e cada série tem os seus próprios atores, mas séries e filmes podem partilhar o mesmo ator. Como é que crio uma foreign key entre Actors.ActorID, MoviesData.ActorID e SeriesData.ActorID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo depende da estrutura que você está criando e os relacionamentos podem mudar:

Caso sua estrutura tenha um ator por serie e filme você pode adicionar uma chave estrangeira em movies e series para actors:

```
ALTER TABLE MoviesData 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Actors) REFERENCES Actors(ActorsID);


ALTER TABLE SeriesData
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Actors) REFERENCES Actors(ActorsID);
```

Caso a sua estrutura Movies e Seires possam ter mais de um Actor então sua estrutura é de N:N, muitos para muitos. Então deve ser criado 2 tabelas de racionamento para MoviesData e SeriesData:

```
CREATE TABLE MoviesData_Actors (
         ActorsID   INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         MoviesDataID  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (ActorsID, MoviesDataID),
         FOREIGN KEY (ActorsID)  REFERENCES Actors(ActorsID),
         FOREIGN KEY (MoviesDataID) REFERENCES MoviesData(MoviesDataID)
)


CREATE TABLE SeriesData_Actors (
         ActorsID   INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         SeriesDataID  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (ActorsID, SeriesDataID),
         FOREIGN KEY (ActorsID)  REFERENCES Actors(ActorsID),
         FOREIGN KEY (SeriesDataID) REFERENCES SeriesData(SeriesDataID)
)
```

Porém caso queria criar uma tabela de relacionamento entre as 3 tabelas basta criar uma tabelas com as 3 chaves e referencia-las.

```
CREATE TABLE SeriesData_Actors (
         ActorsID   INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         SeriesDataID  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         MoviesDataID  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (ActorsID, MoviesDataID  ,SeriesDataID),
         FOREIGN KEY (ActorsID)  REFERENCES Actors(ActorsID),
         FOREIGN KEY (MoviesDataID) REFERENCES MoviesData(MoviesDataID),
         FOREIGN KEY (SeriesDataID) REFERENCES SeriesData(SeriesDataID)
)
```

Espero ter Ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Não será uma FK entre 3 tabelas, será uma tabela independente (`Actors`) e duas dependentes da `Actors` mas independentes entre si.

As ligações serão:

- `Actors` e `MoviesData`
- `Actors` e `SeriesData`

Ou seja, cada uma das tabelas dependentes terão uma FK com a tabela `Actors`

Basta criar uma PK em `Actors`(que será no caso o `ActorID`), e em cada uma das outras tabelas criar um campo (caso não houver) que será ligado ao `Actors.ActorID`, por exemplo `Actors.ActorID`.

Então crie as FK em cada uma das tabelas, no SQL Server a sintaxe seria essa:

```
ALTER TABLE MoviesData
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ActorID) REFERENCES Actors(ActorID);
```